# iOS changing background of both UIStepper tiles

Tags: ios

I want to make use of the `UIStepper` but it's too small for my needs. That's why I found out that

```
[UIStepper setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Gets the stepper as big as the picture is. The problem here is that it sets the background for both "tiles", the + and the - one.

Is there a possibility to change the background of the individual tiles?

Alternatively I could just make 2 buttons work the same way as a stepper does, but just continuing with the stepper would save me 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I had a quick look into the .h file and found:

```
- (void)setDividerImage:(UIImage*)image forLeftSegmentState:(UIControlState)leftState rightSegmentState:(UIControlState)rightState NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
- (UIImage*)dividerImageForLeftSegmentState:(UIControlState)state rightSegmentState:(UIControlState)state NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
```

Which means you can pretty much do your own stile as you can put together the images of the left and the right tile in one file + set a custom divider.